# Keep vim always in command line mode with a ":"

Tags: vim, command, mode

Is there a way to make vim stuck in command mode with a `:` already typed in?

In that way, for instance:

- I would type `/foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and the cursor would go to the beginning of the next line containing `foo`.
- Next, I would be still on command line mode with a `:` already typed in for the next command.

Comment: There's no way to do this.  It's sort of not how Vim operates.  It takes a little while to get used to Vim's three modes, but once you do it'll become automatic.

Comment: @JimStewart: That turns out not to be correct. See my answer.

Comment: @JimStewart - Vim actually has (at least) six modes, (or more, depending on the convention).

Comment: To clarify, do you want to do this while the visual display remains on the screen? My answer assumes you don't, and that you're looking for a purely line-oriented mode.

Comment: @JimStewart: It's likely I misunderstood what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, I was basicly looking for an `ed` with a visual display of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a last try, I could just initialize vim with `-servername=FOO` and then code a little script that would read from stdin and send `remote-send` to FOO whenever it detects(by parsing) a whole command was typed on stdin.

Then I would just use Vim and this other script side by side on different xterms/gnu screens.

> EDIT
>
> OK, I will use this one. This way I can even make `:a` command to enter vim's Insert mode and switch back to command mode when entering a line with a single <kbd>.</kbd>. This way I would also have syntax highlight on the fly when inserting text (you know, vim has a very pretty visual display of the text, I'm just too used with ed's interface). When I have so time I'll write this script and link it here.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, start it in Ex mode, by invoking it either as `ex` or as `vi -e`.

You can also enter Ex mode from the normal visual mode by typing Q (must be upper case).

You can return from Ex mode to normal visual mode by using the `vi` command.

**EDIT** : This doesn't actually do what the OP is looking for. He wants to keep the visual display while keeping the cursor on the bottom command line. That may not be possible.

Comment: When you are in Ex mode, the "visual" window is not updated: you don't  get highlighting or cursor movement which is what the OP is asking for. Hell, when you start in Ex mode there's no "visual" window.

Comment: @romainl: That wasn't clear (at least to me) from the question; the OP didn't specifically say he wanted to keep the visual display. But given the wording ("the cursor would go to the beginning of the next line ..."), you're probably right. I'll post a comment on the question asking for clarification.

Comment: Yes, I want visual display of the text.. Tried to `cmap <cr> <cr>:`, but of course this causes many problems, for instance, when inputing text with ':a`

Comment: And I don't see the point of ex; It doesn't print syntax highlighted text. The <kbd>Up</kbd> key doesn't retype the last command. It doesn't show the visual window (although there is code implemented that does that). I would just stick with ed...

Comment: `ex` is here because `vi` is a `vi`sual mode written for it. Ex is somehow core of Vi(m).

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can map ; to : to put yourself "closer" to command mode.

I'll link to the Vim wiki instead of reposting identical information here.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_semicolon_to_colon

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own *REPL*, like this:

```
:while 1 | execute input(':') | redraw | endwhile
```

This is just a conceptual demo; you probably want to add a condition to quit this special mode. Also, commands like `:append` would need special handling to work properly.

Comment: don't know exactly what to do with it.. writing directly on command or on my .vimrc does not seem to work..

Comment: Type it in Vim :-) After that, you can submit additional Ex commands (like `%s/e/E/g`), and should see its effects applied immediately in the current buffer.

Comment: No, it doesn't work properly. For instance it doesn't jumps to lines when typing numbers, and it breaks everything when a wrong command is entered.

Comment: It does, it just isn't visible. `:redraw!` instead of `:redraw` seems to fix it. As I said, it's just a demonstration that needs to be extended for real use.